# radio button in head of jquery ui accordion causes it to not react

Tags: jquery, debugging, jquery-ui

I have a pretty simple jQuery accordion with radio buttons inside each header.

See this [JSFiddle](http://www.jsfiddle.net/editedredx/zqs2B/)

When i select a radio button it should get checked and the accordion should open on that location. Weird problem is that the accordion opens but the radio doesn't get checked.

To me this looks like a bug in jQuery-ui, any help would be appreciated.

```
<div class="accordion">
    <h3>
        test1
        <input type="radio" checked="checked" name="radio" />
    </h3>
    <div>
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
    </div>
    <h3>
        test2
        <input type="radio" name="radio" />
    </h3>
    <div>
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
    </div>
    <h3>
        test3
        <input type="radio" name="radio" />
    </h3>
    <div>
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
        content<br />
    </div>
</div>
```

js:

```
$(".accordion").accordion()
```

As you can see its about as simple as it can get...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Whatever event you use (the default is `"click"`) will have [`.preventDefault()`](http://api.jquery.com/event.preventDefault/) called on it, so you may just want to change to a similar event, like this:

```
$(".accordion").accordion({ event: "mouseup" });
```

[You cant test it here](http://www.jsfiddle.net/nick_craver/zqs2B/1/).

Comment: I have tweaked @Nick's Fiddle a tiny bit so that clicking anywhere on the accordian header selects the radio button, rather than being required to click the radio button itself. My solution is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/jofitz/zqs2B/492/)